# Initialize an empty Results<T> variable

Tags: ios, swift, variables, initialization, realm

I have a Realm object called `Task`. I'm displaying these tasks in a table view. I have a variable decalred to hold these objects.

```
var tasks: Results<Task>!
```

At initial launch, I'm getting these tasks from an API. Until the local realm is empty. But still when the `UITableViewController` loads, it fires the data source methods. At this point, the `tasks` variable can still be nil. So the app crashes at methods like `numberOfRowsInSection`.

How can I initialize the above variable so that it can be in an empty state and it won't cause crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the app crashes at methods like `numberOfRowsInSection`

Don't let it. *You* are the one who is causing the crash, by *assuming* that `tasks` is not `nil` when in fact it can be. It is *your* job to check in `numberOfSections` to see whether `tasks` *is* `nil`. If it is, return 0 so you don't get asked any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will demonstrate the way how to initialize an empty Results object.

```
class TaskManager {

     private var _realm: Realm?
     var realm: Realm {
         if _realm == nil {           
             _realm = try! Realm()
         }
         return _realm!
     }

     var tasks: Results<Task> = realm.objects(Task.self).filter("FALSEPREDICATE")
}
```

Comment: While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.